# Flutter: "Lost connection to device" error after Hot Reload

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

Here's the full error from the debug console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/FlutterActivityDelegate( 4158): onResume setting current activity to this
D/        ( 4158): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdc74b680, tid 4178
D/EGL_emulation( 4158): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdc741300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdc74c480)
F/libc    ( 4158): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xd in tid 4177 (Thread-2), pid 4158 (le.startupnamer)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PPP4.180612.007/4860066:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 4158, tid: 4177, name: Thread-2  >>> com.example.startupnamer <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xd
Cause: null pointer dereference
eax ca0a8aac  ebx ca0a8aac  ecx 0000000a  edx c9046c80
edi de6638d0  esi c90479f8
ebp c9046b58  esp c9046b58  eip c96e31d8
backtrace:
#00 pc 006981d8  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#01 pc 008f5b75  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#02 pc 008e87ea  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#03 pc 008f3ad6  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#04 pc 008e8b2f  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#05 pc 008ffb03  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#06 pc 008eb310  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#07 pc 008f3d98  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#08 pc 008e8b2f  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#09 pc 008eafc8  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#10 pc 008f997f  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#11 pc 008eaff8  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#12 pc 008fc81c  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#13 pc 008eaf69  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#14 pc 008f997f  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#15 pc 008eaff8  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#16 pc 008ef41e  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#17 pc 008f0570  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#18 pc 0091433e  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#19 pc 0092fad4  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#20 pc 00932f2a  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#21 pc 00934573  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#22 pc 00933d2b  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#23 pc 0093004a  /data/app/com.example.startupnamer-Doz3k_Pl0QfJtnmxYqiyHg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
#24 pc 0000056b  <anonymous:c7680000>
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Flutter extension, but without the Dart extension. I'm also trying to run my Flutter app on an Android emulator, which is a Nexus 6 with API 28 x86. Emulated performance is set to "Hardware - GLES 2.0". The rest of the settings are left as default.

I Cold Boot the emulator before using it with Flutter, due to adb connection problems that prevent the emulator from loading if I start the emulator normally. Possibly not related, but good to note anyway.

Typing `flutter doctor -v` into the command line will show the following:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 0.5.1 at C:\dev\flutter
    • Framework revision c7ea3ca377 (6 weeks ago), 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
    • Engine revision 1ed25ca7b7
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.2
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4668.60

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.25.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

**Now for the actual problem:**

When I load my Flutter app, no matter what kind of state the code is in, the app launches from the state it was in when I saved it for the first time after creation. If I try to make any change to the code (I simply change the theme color) and try to Hot Reload, the app crashes with the error I posted above. Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix this?

There is no error when I load the project, or when I Hot Reload without making any change to the code.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm unable to replicate this bug in Android Studio using the same project. This bug only appears in Visual Studio Code for me.

Comment: I do not quite see through your question. However, it may be helpful to note that I see `le.startupnamer` and `com.example.startupnamer`..

Comment: `startup_namer` is the name of my Flutter project.

Answer (score 4):

One reason I find "**Lost Connection to Device**"

I found this problem when I have added **contacts_service** dependency

If you have installed any plugin that require user permission but you haven't taken permission programatically then you find this error.

To solve this problem manually

- **Goto App Info and Grant Permission Manually in App**

To solve this problem programatically.

- **Take user permission programatically before accessing any plugin**

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix that on my machine. What did the trick for me was to switch do stable channel and update flutter toos with:

```
-flutter upgrade

-flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

I closed VSCode and the emulator. Checked Android Studio as suggested in one of the comments on this thread. Android Studio said that there were no updates available.

Checked flutter upgrade - said that everything was upto date.

Restarted VSCode and emulator and this time it worked fine. Am I missing something? Maybe it just needed a restart?

Answer (score 0):

The first error you posted is a crash and should be [raised on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter). There should be some way to symbolize the stack trace (so it has real method names, etc.) but I can't find instructions for it. It may be the same issue as [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14497) or [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18398), I'm not sure.

> I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Flutter extension, but without the Dart extension.

It's not relevant here, but FYI the Flutter extension has a dependency on the Dart extension, so installing Flutter automatically installs Dart.

> When I load my Flutter app, no matter what kind of state the code is in, the app launches from the state it was in when I saved it for the first time after creation.

This sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16604); it's worth posting that you're having it there to help collect info (I'm not sure if anyone on the Flutter team has been able to reproduce it locally to debug).

> EDIT: I'm unable to replicate this bug in Android Studio using the same project. This bug only appears in Visual Studio Code for me.

Both IDEs use the same tooling so probably there's some subtle difference between the environments (for ex., I think most people run without the debugger in IntelliJ/Android Studio, but with the debugger in VS Code). You can capture logs in VS Code [fairly easily](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#capture-logs-command) but I don't know if IntelliJ/Android Studio have anything similar to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error since 2 months I was able to use the hot reload mode I solved this issue just change our mobile charging cable and use the USB cable for debugging,hope this will help you, if yes then vote up.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Issue was a bad connection between laptop and docking station, and plugging the USB cable into the laptop rather than into the docking station helped.

Answer (score 0):

**update your android sdk, adb, emulator on android studio.**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29968451)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was running the main.dart file whilst I was in IOS folder. After i got to my project folder and ran , I had no issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my situtation, I was seeing "an Unhandled exception about `flutter_isolate` package" in my logs in Android Studio.

So I updated the package to `2.0.3` (latest at that time) version and the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the (most probable) reason was big log size (in Android Studio). I logged big objects. Removing logging big objects solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just update your flutter

$ flutter upgrade --force

Just worked fine for me
Try it