# Unable to run windows desktop app on android studio using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, desktop-application

I'm new to flutter dev and android studio, so basically whenever i run my app on windows(desktop), my app opens for 20sec on windows but then gets closed automatically.

It shows :

> "LOST CONNECTION TO DEVICE" ,

I don't know what is the problem !? I didn't even have the **app.so** file present in any folder, I had to ask a friend to mail me this file, and even after pasting the file in the

build->windows->runner->debug folder, it's showing the same error.

flutter doctor -v result is :

```
C:\Users\Shaurya>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (3 weeks ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Shaurya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.1)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32228.430
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Shaurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 99.0.1150.46

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available


• No issues found!
```

Please help me out !

Comment: Hey Shaurya, without the log I (or others) can't help but the very first thing you can do is check whether all your packages support Windows platform. For that, you can go to [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev) and search for all your packages, the supported platforms are listed below the name of the package. 

If any package doesn't support Windows, you'll have to look for an alternative then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: "Lost connection to device" error after Hot Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263073/flutter-lost-connection-to-device-error-after-hot-reload)

Comment: @LalitFauzdar hey, what's log I ? and also, where do i get to see all my packages ? Even in vs code also, the same problem is coming, my webAPP is running smoothly but desktop and emulator is not, please can you elaborate ? I'm a beginner so I'm little slow at it.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh No , it doesn't. I'm losing my connection even before i could hot reload it. To precise, after 15-20 sec after I run my app on windows, it closes automatically and shows " lost connection to device "

Comment: try [Losing connection to device during start with Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54348224/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh tried things, didn't help